# Numbers sum pattern java

Tags: java

Hello I need to create this pattern in java

[image: pattern]

Im new to this and Im trying different codes but cant find out how to do it.Ive tried this one

```java
 public class JavaProgram
 {
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int i, j, num;
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        num=1;
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(num+ " ");
            num++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}}
```

But the result of this one is

[image: this]

Any help?

Comment: You don't need two loops. Try to figure out how to produce desired output using just one loop.

Comment: @zlakad indeed, you don't *need* two loops; but OP doesn't need to throw away all of his code to make it do what is required. It's simple to adapt what is here already.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I understand your point. It's O.K. with me, but I just gave a tip... When OP *really* think about it, he might become better and better in programming.

Comment: @zlakad and I understand yours. But i would say that to "become better", it is more instructive to look at what it is about the existing code that makes it not work correctly, and think about how to correct it. After all, we don't always have the luxury of throwing it away and starting again. I mean, the changes here are pretty obvious, e.g. if you want `+` between the numbers, don't put a space between them. If you can't even work out that that needs to be changed, you're not going to be able to get very far.

Comment: @AndyTurner, **of course**! It seems to me that we are not so different in opinions (like I said, I gave the tip, not an answer). Good luck, friend.

Answer (score 1):

This solution you'll find quite easier than other answers here :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Write your code here
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = s.nextInt();
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
            sum=0;
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
                sum=sum+j;
                System.out.print(j);
                if(j<i)
                    System.out.print("+");
            }System.out.println("=" + sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a few tries I found the correct code by myself. This is the solution.

```
public class JavaProgram
   {
    public static void main(String args[])
     {
    int i, j, num;
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        num=1;
        int sum=0;
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {

            System.out.print(num+ "");

            sum=sum+num;
            if (num<i) {
                System.out.print("+");
            }  
            num++;

        }

            System.out.print("="+sum);
        System.out.println();
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test
{
    public static void printStars(int n)
    {
        int i, j,temp = 0;

        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(j + " ");

            }
            temp = temp + j - 1;
            if (temp>1) {
                System.out.print(temp + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();

        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n = 10;
        printStars(n);
    }

}
```

Comment: probally your answer is good, but please take some minute to describe what your code does. For future better access to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using While loops

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();

        int row = 1;

        while(n>=row){

            int col = 1;
            int sum = 0;

            while (col<=row){

                sum += col;

                System.out.print(col);

                if(row>col)
                    System.out.print(" + ");

                col++;

                }
            System.out.println(" = " + sum);
            row++;

            }


}
```